# Why does 0xff & abcd truncate half of the abcd?

Tags: math, binary, hex

I can understand binary operation `11 & x`, for example if x = 1011, the operation will take out 10 from x and left x to be 11. However, when it comes to hexadecimal, I am very confused. What is the math and reasoning behind the similar effect of `0xff & x`? I can only understand this if I convert them all to binary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0xFF & 0xABCD = 0xCD` ... why?

```
Because:
A = 1010
B = 1011
C = 1100
D = 1101

F = 1111

So the 0xFF = 0x00FF = 0000 0000 1111 1111
The 0xABCD           = 1010 1011 1100 1101 
                       ------------------- 
0xFF & 0xABCD        = 0000 0000 1100 1101
```

As with most things, once you work with hex for a while, you'll learn some tricks for remembering the values.

Comment: I can easily understand this from binary point of view, but when you just have the hex, how could that still work? I mean, why wouldn't 0xEE truncate ABCD?  
  
EDIT: I am sorry, I just understood your point! Because the 1111 1111 will leave CD below unchanged...! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yup.  0xEE would still strip off the AB, but it would potentially "0" out some data.